# Installing Windows On PC with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, windows

I recently installed Linux Mint on my computer but have decided I would prefer to have a dual boot system.

I wish to re-install my Windows 7 and create a dual boot afterwards but am having trouble i was hoping some of you guys could help me with

When I put in the Windows CD, the computer boots from the CD but then doesn't expand the windows files onto the disk

If I attempt to go to the BIOS, I get transferred to a black screen with a prompt for something called `grub`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You've got to be sure that you have free space on your disk for the Microsoft's (yet) nonposix OS partition, then you can make a normal install and you lose your access to GNU/Linux. Finally you boot a GNU/Linux Live distribution and repair grub (that's a common tutorial).

Comment: Hi, I have tried this with both valid copies of windows XP and Windows 7. Windows 7 kicks me back to grub while windows XP suffers from the blue screen of death

Does Linux mint change the way in which a hard drive stores data and this is the reason windows cant install or am i talking utter nonsense :)

Comment: That could be uncommon, but if you post relevant screenshots it sure can be worked around. If you have a nice cellphone maybe you can take the boot captures.

Comment: It appears i don't have enough points to post pictures. Hopefully my descriptions will suffice

When the laptop boots normally it gets the error here [Link](http://xaxatyxa.ru/_ubuntu/grub-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue.html). When i try to load it from Windows after deleting all partitions i get [link](http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/0/e/5/-/-/windows-7-install-11.jpg) but it never leaves zero percent on the expanding windows files setting

Comment: Getting _error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>_ shows you are failing to install Microsoft without damaging previous GNU/Linux installations. You solve this by installing Microsoft in separate partitions not used by GNU/Linux. Microsoft not expanding its files in the installation is something am sorry not be able to support.

Comment: Hi uprego. There is only a single partition on the PC. When you boot normally without any CD in the DVD drive it now immediately goes to the error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>.
Is the only way to fix this, to find a piece of software that can format the drive completely?

Comment: No, because what you need is not a complete format, but a partitioning scheme of more than one partition.